# Dois on-change em um select

Tags: html, angular

Bom dia, tenho o seguinte código html:

```
      <select class="form-control" formControlName="tipoped" on-change="PesquisaPrazo('prazo', this.digitacaoForm)" on-change="PegarCfop(this.digitacaoForm)" id="q3Id">
        <option selected>Selecione...</option>
        <option *ngFor="let tipo of tipoped" value="{{tipo.Codigo}}">{{tipo.Codigo}} - {{tipo.Nome}}</option>
      </select>
```

Porém só a primeira funcão do on-change é chamada(PesquisaPrazo), a segunda não é acionada. Existe alguma forma de usar dois on-change no mesmo select ou alguma maneira de chamar duas funções no select?

Comment: A resposta que dei funcionou amigo ? Ou tem algo mais que não está dando certo ?

Comment: Está sim, e obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode chamar duas funções assim:

```
<select class="form-control" formControlName="tipoped" on-change="PesquisaPrazo('prazo', this.digitacaoForm); PegarCfop(this.digitacaoForm);" id="q3Id">
   <option selected>Selecione...</option>
   <option *ngFor="let tipo of tipoped" value="{{tipo.Codigo}}">{{tipo.Codigo}} - {{tipo.Nome}}</option>
</select>
```

Mas acho que a melhor forma seria chamar uma função apenas e nela chamar as que você precisa, por exemplo:

```
function OnChange() {
    PesquisaPrazo();
    PegarCfop();
}
```